# Can not delete specific rows in R

Tags: delete-row

I'm trying to delete several rows from my data frame.

```
tww_df4 <- tww_df3[-c(19533, 19543, 19544, 19551, 19552, 19553, 19605, 19614, 19616,
                  19617, 19618, 19623, 19625, 19643, 19653, 19656, 19657),]
```

I do see that the correct number of lines is removed using my code but these were not the lines that I specified.

after looking at the tww_df4 data frame, the rows are still there although 20 rows were deleted and I don't have any error.

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify (and tag) what language you're using?

Comment: Sharing some code example will help